# How to add a column(check Box) in DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows

I have bound `datagridview` by `datatable` of Database on form Load in windows form application and I Want to add a column containing check box.. So whatever is showing can be checked.

Comment: Can you show us your Gridview code please?

Answer (score 6):

You can add easily DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn to your DataGridView Columns:

```
// Create new Checkbox Column
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn myCheckedColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
        {
            Name = "Checked Column", FalseValue = 0 , TrueValue = 1 , Visible = true
        };
// add the new column to your dataGridView 
myDataGridView.Columns.Add(myCheckedColumn);
```

I hope that helps you!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn CBColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
CBColumn.HeaderText = "ColumnHeader";
CBColumn.FalseValue = "0";
CBColumn.TrueValue = "1";
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, CBColumn);
```